# Detecting a change in box2View in jquery Dual ListBox

Tags: jquery

I'm using Dual Listbox jQuery Plug-in with the following code:

```
<div id="instructorSelTab" class="instructorSelTab"> <!-- start div instructorSelTab-->
    <p class="iMsg">Please wait while the list of instructors is generated
        <img class="iImg" src="&save_webPath.css/img/loader.gif"  />
    </p>        
    <table> 
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select id="i1View" multiple="multiple" style="height:300px;width:300px;"></select>
                <br/>
            </td>                          
            <td>
                <button id="ito2"    type="button">&nbsp;>&nbsp;</button><br />
                <button id="iallTo2" type="button">&nbsp;>>&nbsp;</button><br />
                <button id="iallTo1" type="button">&nbsp;<<&nbsp;</button><br />
                <button id="ito1"    type="button">&nbsp;<&nbsp;</button>
            </td>
      <td>
                <select id="i2View" multiple="multiple" style="height:300px;width:300px;"></select>
            <br/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>    
</div> <!-- end div instructorSelTab -->
```

How can I check if the content of i2View has changed? Nothing is selected in i2View and I'm not interested in the content - just the fact that something has changed.

Update: I've tried the following:

```
$("#i1View, #ito2, #i2View").change(function(){
     alert ('changed');
    });
```

Only the i1View triggers the change function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can put a change function on #i1View then if the selected value is 1 (the second one, it starts with 0), then the command that you wish will be triggered.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#i1View").change(function(){
          if($("#i1View").find(":selected").val() == '1'){
             $("#i1View").css('background','green');
          }
          else{
             $("#i1View").css('background','red');
          }
       })
    });
```

Comment: Almost what I need but the change event on i1View gets triggered as soon as the item is selected and even if the item isn't moved to i2View.

Comment: I appreciate the help but again I'm trying to detect changes to i2View so while your answer is helpful it doesn't really do what I asked for.

Comment: As a novice, I'm not familiar with creating a fiddle. I apologize if I've violated some question criteria.